# div to PDF ? Java EE, jQuery, PGSQL

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, postgresql, pdf

I try to catch a div text (an history log from postgresql) for generate in PDF.

Anyone has an idea to implement that?

Does i must generate it in a java servlet or can i do this in jquery?

thanks in advance!

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983730/java-pdf-renderer to use java for pdf render. You must also send the div content to the servlet.

Comment: You cannot generate a PDF with jQuery or any other JavaScript that runs in a browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any library to create pdf form and fields ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656123/is-there-any-library-to-create-pdf-form-and-fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting the cart before the horse here.  Generating a PDF is something you do server side.  Your div is client side, but you probably generated it on the server.

Keep the result of your log on the server somewhere (view scope preferably, but it depends on your server technology) and when the user requests a pdf version, use itext to generate a PDF out of it.

I you really only have your log on client side, you will need to submit it back to the server.  I wouldn't suggest it though.